# In C++11, how to find and return all the item(s) in a vector of strings that start with a given string?

Tags: c++, search

(Note: When I refer to vectors, I'm referring to the `vector` class provided by `<vector>`.)

## The problem

Given a string `x` and a vector of strings, how can I retrieve the string(s) in the vector that start with `x`? Preferably in a way that is time-efficient?

That is, if `x` is `"apple"` and the vector is `vector<string> foods = {"apple pie","blueberry tarts","cherry cobbler"}`, then it should return `"apple pie"` in some capacity.

I am using C++11 and I'm not an expert on it, so simple answers with explanations would be much appreciated. Forgive me if the answer is obvious - I am relatively new to the language.

### Possible solutions I've considered

The obvious solution would be to just create an iterator and iterate through each string in the vector, pulling out all items that start with the given string using the overloaded version of `rfind` that has the `pos` parameter. (That is, like this: `str.rfind("start",0)`)

However, with a large vector this is time-inefficient, so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this, i.e. sorting the vector and using some kind of binary search, or perhaps modifying the `find` method from `<algorithm>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to solve your problem would be to use **binary search**. Note that this requires sorting the `vector` of `strings` first, which gives the algorithm a time complexity of `NlogN`.

```
vector <string> v = {"a", "apple b", "apple c", "d"}; // stuff
string find = "apple";

// create a second vector that contains the substrings of the first vector
vector <pair<string, string>> v2;
for(string item : v){
    v2.push_back({item.substr(0, find.size()), item});
}

sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

// binary search to find the leftmost and rightmost occurrence of find
int l = v.size()-1, r = 0;
for(int i = v.size()/2; i >= 1; i /= 2){
    while(l-i >= 0 && v2[l-i].first >= find){l -= i;}
    while(r+i < v.size() && v2[r+i].first <= find){r += i;}
}

if(v2[l].first == find){
    for(int i = l; i <= r; ++i){
        cout << v2[i].second << endl;
    }
}
else{
    cout << "No matches were found." << endl;
}
```

In my code, we first create a second `vector` called `v2` to store pairs of `strings`. After sorting it, we implement **binary search by jumps** to find the leftmost and rightmost occurrences of `find`. Lastly, we check if there are any occurrences at all (this is an edge case), and print all the found `strings` if occurrences exist.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thank you! I was thinking of using binary search to attack the problem so this will be very helpful.

Comment: Sorting the vector is O(n log n) which is slower than just doing one linear scan through the vector and copying matched strings. Use `std::copy_if` with a lambda and it's practically a one-liner.

Comment: It's not always slower; the complexity of a linear scan would be O(N*L) where L is the length of the string to be searched for, meaning that the binary search algorithm would run faster when the size of L is greater than log(N). However, I agree that a linear scan would be shorter and easier to implement.

Comment: A binary search is fast but you have to include the cost of sorting the vector first.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to copy desired strings would be a simple linear scan. For example, using the standard library [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to perform the copying and a lambda to encapsulate the "starts with" string comparison.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> foods = { "apple pie","blueberry tarts","cherry cobbler" };

    std::string prefix{ "apple" };
    auto starts_with = [&prefix](const std::string &str) {
        return str.compare(0, prefix.size(), prefix) == 0;
    };

    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::copy_if(begin(foods), end(foods), back_inserter(result), starts_with);

    for (const auto &str : result) {
        std::cout << str << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a single pass over the vector.  This is the best you'll do unless the vector is pre-sorted, since the cost of sorting will outweigh any gain you get from using a binary search.

Using [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) makes this pretty simple:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v = {
        "apple pie",
        "blueberry tarts",
        "apple",
        "cherry cobbler",
        "pie"
    };
    
    std::vector<std::string> v2;
    std::string to_find = "apple";
    std::copy_if(
        v.begin(),
        v.end(),
        std::back_inserter(v2),
        [&to_find](const std::string& el) {
            return el.compare(0, to_find.size(), to_find) == 0;
        }
    );
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e57853c23d801945)

This will copy all elements from `v` that match the predicate function into `v2`.  The predicate simply checks that the first `to_find.size()` characters of each element match the string to find using [`std::string::compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) (overload (2) on that page).